# Returning raw memory in Python-3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am extending Python by a C-library which returns some memory. In one case the caller owns the memory, in the second one the callee owns the memory (both cases read/write memory). What type of object should I return in Python 3? I know for instance PyCapsule and memoryview. PyCapsules can delete the memory and take over the ownership but has less functions available in Python code whereas memoryview is just a view and can't take over the ownership. What would you do?

**Example 1**

```
static PyObject *Foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywords)
{
    void* mem = malloc(size);
    foo::FillMemory(mem, size);
    return ???(mem, size)?
}
```

Example 2:

```
static PyObject *Bar(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywords)
{
    size_t size;
    void* mem = foo::GetMemory(mem, &size);
    return ???(mem, size)?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python code, ideally you don't operate on "some memory". You operate on objects, through members that are specific to the types of those objects. So, neither one. Return your own custom type, with whatever members -- and whatever ownership semantics -- make sense for that particular type.